# Taking a user input to change and apply it in a different way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone please show me a way where I can take a user input like "Link = http://google.com" and change that into "< link src=" the users link ">< /link>"?

I already have a code that takes the users input and changes it into something else, but I want to be able to add more stuff to the replaced words. 
So when the user types "link" it automatically changes to "< link src=" " > " 
but I also want it in a way so that when the user types in Link = http://google.com , it puts the users link into the src.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ref.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$('.chatinput').keyup(function (event) {
newText = event.target.value;
for (var txt in replaceValues) {
    var temp = new RegExp(txt, 'gim');
    newText = newText.replace(temp, '\n' + replaceValues[txt]);
}
$('.printchatbox').val(newText);
});





var replaceValues = {
'string' : 'text',
'sample' : 'sample'
}
```

Comment: [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)s have `href`, `src` is meaningless. Maybe you need [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) instead?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it says href or src at this point :D. I just need help with being able to add the users link into the href= or src= instead of the user having to manually write Link = " http://.... " ...

Comment: That was just in case ... Usually these kind of editors adds a link when user types an URL, no need for separate keywords.

Comment: Okay, but when a user types in URL along with the link, how can I add that with the already replaced words from their input, and output them together to have one line of code that has their link tag & the link itself. 

FYI: Sorry for using the < link > as an example. My mind was thinking about XML when I wrote that. I meant < a href= " " /> at the beginning :D